# ZF2 console app not able to read array from file

Tags: arrays, file, console, zend-framework2

I am trying to setup a console route for my zf2 application for a cron job.
But when it comes to reading on array from a file like `module.config.php` or language files it throws on exception : InvalidArgumentException with message : Excepted on array but received on integer.

At first i was getting this error for a module config file, so i thought it could be because of a BOM or something so i re-created the module config file and the exception wend away , but now of the language files is giving the same error and i tried rebuilding the file but it had no effect?

what could cause this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid. some of those files had `<?` and some had `<?php` and short_open_tag was off for cli :D

NOTICE : for every one be warned when using wamp on local development server changing settings from right-click context menu WILL NOT change the setting for console php , u need to modify the php.ini file in the php folder itself.